# Looking for Linear Algebra resource (problems and solutions)

Tags: linear-algebra

I work for a small research company, and one of my bosses wants me to teach him how to use the LAPACK libraries for Fortran.  I have never used Fortran or LAPACK, so I am looking for a book of linear algebra problems with solutions so I can use it to practice using the libraries, figure out the arguments, etc., and know that I am getting the right results.

Any suggestions?  Again, I am just looking for a resource with lots of questions where the answers are already given.  I don't want to work them all out by hand if I don't have to.  Thanks!

Comment: Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra and its Applications, Fourth Edition has a lot of exercises and solutions.  Here's a link to the whole book in pdf: http://math.bnu.edu.cn/~lijiequan/publications/Strang_Linear.Algebra.and.Its.Applications.4ed.pdf

Comment: And here's a solution manual for another version of Strang: http://www.math.montana.edu/~parker/courses/M221/Partial%20solutions%20manual%20for%20Strang.pdf

Comment: Lapack is written in fortran, but you need not use fortran to use Lapack.  For example, if you use numpy or scipy linear algebra (for python), then these functions call Lapack directly.  This is similar in many languages, their built-in numerical linear algebra libraries make calls to lapack for you.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  If you just need questions to solve, the Schaum's outline for linear algebra is very cheap (<\$10) and is mostly just a bunch of questions (most of which have solutions).

Comment: Thanks, but the boss himself uses Fortran for everything, so that's what I gotta use.

Comment: As far as I know, Fortran XXX for Scientists and Engineers by Chapman (where XXX is either 90/95 or 95/2003) contains a lot of exercises (I'm not sure about solutions now). I'm not aware about a book teaching both Fortran and LAPACK, but the [LAPACK User's Guide](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug) is certainly the best way how to get to know it.